# bash_aliases are not working in Ubuntu run (Alt+F2) dialog

Tags: 18.04, bash, gnome-shell, alias

`bash_aliases` are not working in Ubuntu run (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) dialog. It shows a "*Command not found*" error.
[image]

But it works perfectly in Terminal.

How can I make it working in run command box?

Comment: You have to launch a terminal and run the alias